# CentOS upgrade PHP compile modules

Tags: php

I'm currently using CentOS 6.4 which by default comes with PHP 5.3.3 (installed via `yum install php`). I now wish to upgrade to the latest version of PHP. I already downloaded and compiled PHP. However, before `make install`ing I'd like to know if:

1. I should remove the old PHP package via yum first
2. I need to recompile all the PHP modules (e.g. `yum install php-mbstring`) for them to work with the new version of PHP

Comment: The remi yum repos have up-to-date versions of php for centos - http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

Comment: I do not get it. If you are using compiled version of php why do you need yum install php-mbstring?

Comment: I already installed mbstring and other modules when the system was first set up. It's just now that I want to upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the remi repository. I was aware of that. However, I'd like to understand how this works. I don't really know much about how linux package managers work--or the PHP modules for that matter. So it'd be nice if someone could answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-php56/

```
# 1. Install the Software Collections tools:
yum install scl-utils

# 2. Download a package with repository for your system.
#  (See the Yum Repositories section below. You can use `wget URL`.)

# 3. Install the repo package:
yum install rhscl-rh-php56-*.noarch.rpm

# 4. Install the collection:
yum install rh-php56

# 5. Start using software collections:
scl enable rh-php56 bash
```